# Generic Interfaces Extends?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, interface

Hi I have this question on Generic interfaces if someone could explain the answer to me in a detailed way ill be extremely grateful.

**Inteface I**

```
public interface I <T> {
void  f (T a);
}
```

**Interface J**

```
public interface J <T extends I<T>>{
  void g(T b);
}
```

**Class A**

```
public class A<T> implements J<T>{
    public void g(T b) {

    }
}
```

**The Code In Class A will give an error.**
Could You explain to me why it gives an error?

**Class A FIX**

```
public class A<T extends I<T>> implements J<T>{
    public void g(T b) {

    }
}
```

Could Someone explain to me why this code fixes the error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `J <T extends I<T>>`, so when you implement this interface you need to provide it with class T that extends I. But you cannot write it like this `A<T> implements J<T extends I<T>>`. I guess that it is not what you wanted because it creates unnecessary requirements for class T.

So what I would change is:

First: `J <T extends I<T>>` change to  `J<T> extends I<T>`. Now you have simpler type for J. And I think that this is what you need/want anyways.

Second: you should implement all methods, fi(T x) and fj(T x), so just do that.

And here is working example how it is done. Simple and working.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A<String>();
        a.fi("foo");
        a.fj("bar");
        return;
    }

    public interface I<T> {
        void  fi(T t);
    }

    public interface J<T> extends I<T> {
      void fj(T t);
    }

    public static class A<T> implements J<T> { 
        // it is static only to be accessible from main()
        public A() {
            // default constructor
        }

        public void fi(T t) {
            System.out.println("method from I, arg=" + b.toString());
        }

        public void fj(T t) {
            System.out.println("method from J, arg=" + b.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
method from I, arg=foo
method from J, arg=bar
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `T` does not extend/implement `I<T>`.

It is often confusing to use the same generic placeholder. Try looking at it like this:

```
public interface I<TI> {
    void f(TI a);
}

public interface J<TJ extends I<TJ>> {
    void g(TJ b);
}

// Error:(17, 37) java: type argument TA is not within bounds of type-variable TJ
// i.e. This `TA` does NOT implement/extend J<TA extends I<TA>>
public class A<TA> implements J<TA> {
    public void g(TA b) {

    }
}

// Works fine because `TB extends I<TB>`
public class B<TB extends I<TB>> implements J<TB> {
    public void g(TB b) {

    }
}
```